# Rails insert dynamic fields into the database

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a simple app with a single model (task) and a single attribute (name).

## app/views/tasks/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag :action => 'create' %>
<div id="dynamicInput">
          Task Name <input type="text" name="task[name][]">
     </div>
     <input type="button" value="Add New Tag" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
<%= submit_tag "Create"%>
```

## app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
var counter = 1;
function addInput(divName){
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  newdiv.innerHTML = "Task Name <input type='text' name='task[name][]'>";
  document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
  counter++;
}
```

The code above allows me to add as many fields as I like. I am able to enter a single name, but if I dynamically add 2 fields, here are what my params look like...

```
Started POST "/tasks" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-25 12:36:57 -0400
Processing by TasksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PnTQnxM3GFRtqkXi09jLH8UJBiaRCI0chSZ716cVWJ0=", "task"=>{"name"=>["name1", "name2"]}, "commit"=>"Create"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (5.6ms)  INSERT INTO "tasks" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Thu, 25 Jul 2013 16:36:57 UTC +00:00], ["name", ["name1", "name2"]], ["updated_at", Thu, 25 Jul 2013 16:36:57 UTC +00:00]]
   (153.1ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/tasks/1
Completed 302 Found in 165ms (ActiveRecord: 158.7ms)
```

I want a separate task/name for each name I enter.

Comment: I think field should be named `task[name][]`. Why are you not using Rails form helpers? - life's way easier with them.

Comment: is name set as an accessible attribute on your model?

Comment: Thanks Michael, making that change allowed me to submit a single task name. I updated my question. Now if I insert a 2nd name, I do not get two separate tasks. Ideas? Also, I am open to form helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails 4, the Strong Parameters feature requires that you whitelist params inside your controller. Also, according to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549382/how-to-permit-an-array-with-strong-parameters), an array of params can't be whitelisted without a further tweak, so you need

```
params.require(:task).permit(name: [])
```

Comment: Good call as I was using Rails 4 in addition to Rails 3 for testing this out. The real problem I am trying to solve to with the JavaScript.

Comment: Are you making multiple *tasks*, or multiple *tags* on one task?

Comment: Sorry about that...wrong console grab. Fixed above. So in the submission above I entered task 1 and task 2, but only got a singe task entered into the db with the name name1 - name2. what I want to 2 separate tasks...name1, and another task, name2

Comment: In that case, you need to iterate through the task[:name] array in the controller: `task[:name].each{|individual_name| Task.create(name: individual_name)}`

Comment: That works dude. I will update your answer and mark as correct. Thanx!