# What is the best way to pass many checkboxes values to strong param

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a page with 10 checkboxes that translate into true/false based on the user selection
at the moment my strong param method looks like

```
def checkbox_params
    params.require(:"{}").permit(:param1, :param2, :param3,...)
end
```

based on this I iterate over each value and check if it is true/false before I commit the information to my database. If in the future I will add more params this list will become big
and I will have a long for iteration.
Is there a better practice to pass this information?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array of check boxes so you only end up with 1 param to permit.

Rails will take each checked value and then append it to an array which ends up being the value of the param. Then you can just `.each` through the array and do your comparisons there.

Comment: can you pass an array in strong params?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549382/how-to-permit-an-array-with-strong-parameters I guess you can. I will accept you answer in the next few minutes

Comment: Can strong-params take a regexp, such as `/^check\d+/`? or am I being a newb bc I haven't read about them or used them yet.