# Rails access serialized array in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following class:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :choices
end
```

I want my questions to have a set of choices that the user can select, and I'm storing them inside the question record to avoid a second database query.  I'm trying to set my form so that the text for each choice is editable by a user.  This is the tag I'm using for the input:

```
<input name="question[choices][]" type="text" />
```

My permit function is this:

```
def question_params
  params.require(:question).permit(:category_id, :content, :choices, :answer_id)
end
```

My choices array isn't getting set.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you using Rails 4?

Comment: Yes.  This is a dummy sentence to get by SO's comment length minimum.  =)

Comment: Can you share your strong parameters `permit` call? I'm thinking this may be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549382/how-to-permit-an-array-with-strong-parameters

Comment: Added to original question

Comment: Peter, your link pointed me in the right direction.  If you want to answer the question, I'll give you the credit.

Comment: Thanks. Let me know if I didn't get it right for your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the introduction of strong parameters, arbitrary non-scalar values are no longer accepted as input values. If you want to pass an array of scalars, however, you can declare that in your `permit` statement as in:

```
params.require(:question).permit(:category_id, :content, :choices => [], :answer_id)
```

This can be a difficult problem to detect, however, as the input values can simply be ignored without an error in some cases (the specifics of which I don't recall off-hand).

This is discussed further in [how to permit an array with strong parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549382/how-to-permit-an-array-with-strong-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Try below.. (Controller code?)

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :choices,Array
end
```