# Saving array through form not working correctly (using checkboxes and simple_form)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, checkbox, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'm trying to create an Email record, which can be saved as different types. For example an email that will be sent to all users, or one that will be sent to certain writers only.

Every option works except from the writers one, in which I'm trying to use checkboxes to save an id array, rather than retrieving the id array from the database.

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :subject, :body
  serialize :user_ids
  after_create :set_user_ids

  ...

  private

  def set_user_ids
    if mass_email?
      array = User.pluck(:id)
    elsif user_email?
      ...
    end
    self.user_ids ||= array
    self.max_mailings = user_ids.size
    save!
  end
end
```

The form (using [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)):

```
<%= simple_form_for [:admin, @email] do |f| %>
  <% if writers?(params[:email_type]) %>
    <%= f.input :sent_to, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: "Writers" } %>
    <%= f.input :user_ids, collection: Writer.all.collect{ |w| [w.name, w.id] }, as: :check_boxes, label: false %>
    <br>
  <% end %>

  ...
<% end %>
```

The html:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/emails" class="simple_form new_email" id="new_email" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
  ...
  <div class="control-group check_boxes optional email_user_ids">
    <div class="controls">
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input class="check_boxes optional" id="email_user_ids_1" name="email[user_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
        John Smith
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input class="check_boxes optional" id="email_user_ids_2" name="email[user_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="2" />
        Bob Brown
      </label>
      <input name="email[user_ids][]" type="hidden" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

The usual `new` and `create` action:

```
class Admin::EmailsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @email = Email.new
  end

  def create
    @email = Email.new(email_params)
    if @email.save
      flash[:success] = "Email saved successfully."
      redirect_to [:admin, @email]
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def email_params
    params.require(:email).permit(:subject, :body, :email_type, :user_ids, :max_mailings, :sent_to)
  end
end
```

But when I try to submit the following error occurs, even though the `user_ids` param is present:

```
undefined method 'size' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #51):

49  end
50    self.user_ids ||= array
51    self.max_mailings = user_ids.size
52    save!
53  end

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"cVyUQY7Faqr6JpkdGoPwLhe+Pv6ld/7vzXLvBg+tzsk=",
 "email"=>{"sent_to"=>"Writers",
 "user_ids"=>["1",
 "2",
 ""],
 "subject"=>"Email to writers",
 "body"=>"Email to writers",
 "email_type"=>"writers"},
 "commit"=>"Create Email"}
```

I can't figure out why `user_ids` isn't updated correctly.
Also I'm not sure why an extra `email[users_id][]` field is rendered as a hidden field.

Comment: it think u had missed self before user_ids

Comment: params are not accessible inside model

Comment: In Rails you don't have to add the `self`. Doing `self.user_ids` and `user_ids` is exactly the same in this case. It's just convention to add `self` when assigning a value.

Comment: I'm not trying to access the params though. They should already be saved through the form. I'm using `after_create` to update other attributes based on what's saved (or not saved).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your problem may lie with your email_params method. Check out [how to permit an array with strong parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549382/how-to-permit-an-array-with-strong-parameters). It looks like you may need to explicitly declare that user_ids will be an Array.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I'll give you the bounty when it lets me.