# Rails 4 PostgreSQL Array Type Problems - undefined method `gsub' for Fixnum

Tags: arrays, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I recently tried adding an Array type column in my Rails app which uses Postgres 9.3. I followed some online tutorials and added the following code into my project.

**Migration**

```
add_column :matches, :p1_characters, :string, array: true, default: []
add_column :matches, :p2_characters, :string, array: true, default: []
```

Now if I try to manually update a match's characters in the console like so:

```
> m = Match.first
> m.p1_characters = ["1","2","3"]
> m.save
# Works fine!
```

Everything saves correctly in the database as expected.

The problem lies in trying to update the p1_characters/p2_characters attributes in my rails app.

**p1_edit_character_.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@match, method: :patch,
                           :url => p1_set_character_match_path(@match)) do |f| %>

# displays a form of check boxes where the user can select multiple characters.

  <h1>Select P1 Character</h1>
  <%= f.input :p1_characters, label: "Player 1 Character", as: :check_boxes, 
                              collection: @characters %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Select Character", class: "btn-lg btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I know that the params being passed to my controller is:

```
"match"=>{"p1_characters"=>["1", "2", "3", ""]}
```

The error I get is

```
undefined method `gsub' for 1:Fixnum
```

Below is my controller with the relevant methods and strong params
**matches_controller.rb**

```
def p1_edit_character
  @match = Match.find(params[:id])
  @characters = Game.find(@match.game_id).characters
end

def p1_set_character
  @match = Match.find(params[:id])
  if @match.update_attributes(match_params)
    if @match.p1_characters != []
    flash[:notice] = "P1 character set."
  end
    redirect_to matches_path
  end
end

private
  def match_params
    params.require(:match).permit(:p1_score, :p2_score, :match_date, 
    :p1_accepted, :p2_accepted, {p1_characters: []}, {p2_characters: []},
    :disputed, :finalized_date)
  end
```

Please, any guidance would be so helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi.  Passing an array as a strong parameter may be messing you up.  As per [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549382/how-to-permit-an-array-with-strong-parameters), in `match_params`, explicitly make :p1_caracters an array as in `params.require(:match).permit(:p1_score, :p2_score, :match_date, :p1_accepted, :p2_accepted, :p1_characters => [], :p2_characters)`

Comment: Hey BenU, I've run into a new error now. I added {p1_characters: []} into my strong parameters but now I get this error: undefined method `gsub' for 44:Fixnum

Comment: You're getting closer.  Have you tried googling your new error message?  There seems to be a number of posts with insight into your new one.  GTEM.

Comment: It's a rails bug https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13444