# Array in Rails 4 strong parameters (not nested)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I want to create several objects at a time, from my index view, so I have inputs: `post[][title]` and `post[][parent_id]`, in my `post_controller.rb` i have:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title => [], :parent_id => [])
end
```

But I'm getting the error on submit: `undefined method 'permit' for [{"title"=>"Title", "parent_id"=>"133"}]:Array`

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549382/how-to-permit-an-array-with-strong-parameters), but if I try `params.permit(:title => [], :parent_id => [])`, then `post_params` just returns empty hash.

params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"oJwfzxbn+LJ/pD1hKo27gckZg6P4Gd8wyNY9NSFS4BA=",
"post"=>{"title"=>["1",
"2"],
"parent_id"=>["",
""]},
"locale"=>"ru"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in Cancancan strong params, despite [the following article](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Strong-Parameters) I could not get cancancan gem to use my `post_params` function (i have `load_and_authorize_resource` call in `ApplicationController`), so the fix was to use `skip_load_resource :only => :create` in my `PostController`.

Note: due to [this issue](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/pull/88) writing `skip_load_resource :only => :create` in `ApplicationController` won't work.