# How to post all checked check_box values to 1 field as an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

Post and save as array to postgres db.

```
<% ['auto', 'homeowners', 'health'].map do |service| %>
  <div class="element element-float">
    <%= check_box_tag 'agent[agent_services]', [service] %> <%= service %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Currently submitting the form will only save the last item on the page checked. So if I try to check "auto" and "homeowners" only "homeowners" is saved. Rails log:

```
"agent"=>{"agent_services"=>"homeowners"}
```

What I need to do is save all of the checked elements into ROW#agent_services as an array. So if I check "auto" and "homeowners", I need the following to happen:

```
"agent"=>{"agent_services"=>["auto", "homeowners"]}
```

I can do this with js but I want to know the rails way. Also the next problem is that postgresql#agent_services == String .. Is there a way to make this row accept an array?

Thanks!

Having an issue saving to postgres
column is `add_column :agents, :agent_services, :string, array: true`

```
params.require(:agent).permit( . . . , :agent_services => [])

Processing by AgentsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"t/aqjJWwd24czZNXKVS5q9yjf6WU15/artpAaXtb28s=", "agent"=>{"agent_services"=>["auto", "homeowners", "health"]}, "button"=>"", "id"=>"60"}
  Agent Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "agents".* FROM "agents"  WHERE "agents"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 60]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE "agents" SET "agent_services" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "agents"."id" = 60  [["agent_services", "{\"auto\",\"homeowners\",\"health\"}"], ["updated_at", "2014-09-17 18:50:52.190149"]]
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "agent_services" is of type character varying[] but expression is of type character varying at character 40
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
: UPDATE "agents" SET "agent_services" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "agents"."id" = 60
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Comment: Also I suggest you to use a constant as the different check box options in order to keep it defined at one place, then do a double-check on the server side that the values in `agent_services` only includes stuff that is defined in this constant ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it:

```
check_box_tag 'agent[agent_services][]', [service]
```

will provide you params like you wanted:

```
"agent"=>{"agent_services"=>["auto", "homeowners"]}
```

Comment: This is strange.. Getting "Unpermitted parameters: agent_services" but it is in the permit array. Do I need to change something?

Comment: Yes I think you have to declare the `agent_services` as an Array (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549382/how-to-permit-an-array-with-strong-parameters)

Comment: Yeah do you know about postgresql cast types? Updated the question

Comment: Sorry ment to plus you not accept.. question isn't solved for me quite yet

Comment: This actually concerns another subject and should be asked in another post. But we can try to solve it here. They way Rails is trying to save the `agent_services` attribute's value is as a Ruby Array in the DB. This can be done via serialization of the `agent_services` attribute: `serialize :agent_servers, :array`.

Comment: Some how restarting the server fixed the problem... Thanks!