# Cannot get a many-to-many item to save to the database when using a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a many-to-many relationship between **Notes** and **Stacks**.  I am creating a form where a user can create a new note, with a title, body, and then a group of check boxes.  The group of checkboxes are various Stacks.  I want a user to be able to associate one or multiple Stacks with a particular note.

I am using the [simple_form gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) to do this.  Everything is working **except** the Stacks will not save to the database.  The title and body save, but not the Stacks.  I have tested both sides of the relationship manually in the console, and they **do** yield the expected results -- it works.

One thing I notice when I watch what is going on in the Rails Server tab is `Unpermitted parameters: stack_ids`, as seen here:

```
Started POST "/notes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-06 16:00:21 -0600
Processing by NotesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"gMpbaYio0qkPLLrR6ICG0IJ7XNoy3Rn4RHLm3vwUU+I=", "note"=>{"title"=>"asdfs ", "body"=>"asdfasdf  asfsadf ", "stack_ids"=>["1", "2", ""]}, "commit"=>"Create Note"}
Unpermitted parameters: stack_ids
```

My `notes_controller.rb` has these params:

```
def notes_params
  params.require(:note).permit(:title, :body, :stack_id)
end
```

My `stacks_controller.rb` has these params:

```
def stacks_params
  params.require(:stack).permit(:title, :description, :note_id)
end
```

Here is the form:

`<%= simple_form_for @note, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f|  %>
    <%= f.input :title, placeholder: ":title", id: "note-form-title-field", class: "note-form-fields" %>
    <%= f.input :body, placeholder: ":body", id: "note-form-body-field", class: "note-form-fields"  %>
    <%= f.association :stacks, as: :check_boxes %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>`

I have tried replacing `:stack_id` in the params with other variations, and always get the same result.  Any ideas on how to get these **Stacks** to save to the database, associated with a note?  Thanks.

Comment: version of rails? 3 has `attr_accessible` and 4 has `strong_params`. also, check my edits for formatting =)

Comment: `.permit`... duh. rails 4. try allowing stack, and not stack_id.

Comment: Thanks. Version 4.1.  Tried `:stack`, and `:stacks` and other variations.  Same results.

Comment: what does your form look like?

Comment: I added the form above

Comment: It seems like you're permiting stack_id and passing stack_ids... Already tried to permit stack_ids?

Comment: Try permitting stack_ids like this: `params.require(:note).permit(:title, :body, :stack_ids => [])`. It's the usual way to allow a list of ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [StackOverflow posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549382/how-to-permit-an-array-with-strong-parameters/16555975#16555975) provides a detailed solution.

In summary, when declaring strong parameters, I needed to explicitly map the `stack_ids` key to an empty array in my `notes_controller.rb` file:

`def notes_params
    params.require(:note).permit(:title, :body, stack_ids: [])
  end`