# Mongoid doesn't change the value of Array if sent params with missing field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, parameters

I'm using Rails 4.2 and using the `.update_attributes` method.

After some debugging it's come to my attention that if the field is MISSING from the params, Mongoid will just keep the old value of the param.

Edit: It seems that no matter what I do, the following code doesn't work:

```
campaign = Campaign.find_by username: params[:id]
campaign.update_attributes params[:campaign].permit!
```

Here's what does work:

```
campaign.attributes = params[:campaign].permit! 
# .update_attributes(params[:camapign]) would likely work, too
campaign.allowed_brokers = params[:campaign][:allowed_brokers]
campaign.custom_payouts = params[:campaign][:custom_payouts]
campaign.save
```

Both allowed_brokers and custom_payouts are `Array` type fields. It seems that line 1 takes care of anything that's not an array field.

I'm 100% sure that incoming `params` don't contain the old values (in fact, they're missing from `params[:campaign]` - there's no `params[:campaign][:allowed_bidders]` for example.

Why is Mongoid not updating the array fields?

Thanks in advance.

PS: Here's the model:

```
class Campaign
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic

  field :name,                  type: String

  # ==== Other irrelevant fields ====

  # List of brokers and corresponding share %
  field :custom_payouts,        type: Array, default: []

  # Taggable strings
  field :allowed_brokers,       type: Array, default: []
  field :allowed_bidders,       type: Array, default: []
  field :can_start,             type: Array, default: []
  field :can_pause,             type: Array, default: []

  # Associations
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bidders
end
```

PPS: I'm still trying to figure out why I have to manually amend the array fields. Meanwhile I've also found that despite the fact the fields are of type `Array` with a defined default of `[]`, they can be set to null directly in the database which is bad. How do I avoid that? Maybe `Attributes::Dynamic` has something to do with that? If so, how'd I manually amend Arrays without it?

Comment: Yes, that was my first guess. It's EXACTLY the params I want to send, NOT including some fields.

Comment: Have you looked at this answer? It might be the permit error http://stackoverflow.com/a/16555975/1769515

Comment: i have a feeling that's not it. I looked at mongoDB docs and it seems that you have to specify explicitly which fields you're updating and since I'm not, they aren't... that's my leading theory at the moment