# Rails 4 Checkboxes: Not getting saved to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I'm using Rails 4 and I have 3 models: property, category, and categorization.

The application is here: https://github.com/ornerymoose/PropertiesAndCategories

The idea: you can update a property and there's 6 categories (6 checkboxes) to choose from.

I came across this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549382/how-to-permit-an-array-with-strong-parameters) and it was helpful but alas, my values still aren't getting saved.

When I click the update button to update a property: the server logs (if I select checkboxes 3 4 and 5) will be:

```
**Processing by PropertiesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Dcgy+3qBF4JLeu5MMATyqOc+jWyILXTfgURbqn+Ez8E2ru3rpzgPBqKDPWsy/QelQuQgOczdC8xDsOnnwSDAnQ==", "property"=>{"name"=>"Vizcaya", "category_id"=>["3", "4", "5", ""]}, "commit"=>"Update Property", "id"=>"6"}**
```

If I fire up rails console and check out the ^above property, category_id is set to nil. Why is this? My strong params are correct in the properties_controller I think:

```
def property_params
  params.require(:property).permit(:name, :category_id => [])
end
```

Any and all input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have ":category_id => []"? I'm pretty sure if you get rid of the "=> []" portion and just treat :category_id like :name (as I've shown below), it should work!

```
def property_params
  params.require(:property).permit(:name, :category_id)
end
```

Comment: No luck. Have you tested this? Using either `category_id` `category_ids` returns the following in the Rails server log: `Unpermitted parameter: category_id`

Comment: @DnfD server restarted?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the first fix was here in the properties controller:

```
def property_params
  params.require(:property).permit(:name, :category_ids => [])
end
```

I was initially using `:category_id => []` which didn't return an error in the Rails server log, but wasn't saving the checkbox values to the database.

And then the second fix was fixing the `collection_check_boxes` arguments. Initially I had `:category_id` but I completely overlooked that it had to be `:category_ids`:

```
<%= collection_check_boxes(:property, :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name)
```

Everything is working well now.