# How can get array values using has_and_belongs_to_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Can't save params selected on select box.

Table **users**:

```
1id| |name|
1     CR7
2     Messi
```

Table **ejecutives**:

```
1id| |name|
1     Mourinho
2     Guardiola
```

Table **user_ejecutives**:

```
|id| |user_id|  |ejecutive_id|
1     1          1    
2     2          2
```

Controller **users_controller.rb**:

```
def new
  @obj_user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new user_params
  @user.save
end

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

private
 def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:name, user_ejecutive_ids: [])
 end
```

Models:

```
#User.rb
has_many :ejecutives, :through => :user_ejecutives
has_many :user_ejecutives
has_and_belongs_to_many :user_ejecutives, class_name: "User", join_table: "user_ejecutives"#, foreign_key: :user_id, association_foreign_key: :ejecutive_id  

#Ejecutive.rb
has_many :user_ejecutives
has_many :users, :through => :user_ejecutives

#UserEjecutive.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :ejecutive
```

View **new.html.erb**:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= form.text_field :name %>
   <%= f.collection_select :user_ejecutive_ids, Ejecutive.all, :id, :name, multiple: true %>
<% end %>
```

View **show.html.erb**

```
<% @user.ejecutives.each do |ejecutive| %>
  <%= ejecutive.name %></label>
<% end %>
```

I'm not getting results on the view show and it show on logs:

```
SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
```

Comment: You have a typo here: `params.requite("user_ejecutives[]")`. "requite" instead of "require"

Comment: Use Dheeresha's answer, but watch out for that typo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to permit an array with strong parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549382/how-to-permit-an-array-with-strong-parameters)

Comment: I have updated my code, Kindly check if this update works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to populate the join table (`user_ejecutives`), you'll want to populate the [`singular_colletion_ids`](https://ernie.io/2010/10/02/the-underused-collection_singular_ids-method/) method:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def new
     @user = User.new
   end

   def create
     @user = User.new user_params
     @user.save
   end

   private

   def user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:name, user_ejecutive_ids: [])
   end
end

#app/views/users/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select :user_ejecutive_ids, User.all, :id, :name, multiple: true %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will assign new `user_ejecutives` for each new `@user` you create.

PS `User.all` is valid in this instance as you're dealing with a new (uncreated) `@user` record, hence it won't appear in the db.

---

If you wanted to *create* new `user_ejecutives` with each new `@user`, you'll want to use [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), which I can explain if required.

---

**Update**

So your error is as follows:

```
Unpermitted parameter: user_ejecutive_ids
```

... you also have another error...

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
```

This is exactly why I don't like your code. Because it doesn't fit to convention, you've go to evaluate whether the params are present etc.

You'll need to use the controller code I posted - it will populate the other table for you, and fix this `NilClass` error.

--

**Join Table**

Your `user_ejecutives` table is a *join* table.

Your `User` model should have the following:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :user_ejecutives, class_name: "User", join_table: "user_ejecutives", foreign_key: :user_id, association_foreign_key: :ejecutive_id
end
```

You'll have to remove the `id` column from your `user_ejecutives` table (as per the definition [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)). The importance of this is that it gives you the ability to populate the `singular_collection_ids` method (in your case `user_ejective_ids`), as per my recommended code.

Comment: It's not (it opens the door to so potential sql injection). If you post your request log, I'll give you the correct definition

Comment: Have you tested my code? I really don't like yours, it's too cumbersome

Comment: Let's check it out!!

Comment: Up to you, I can only recommend what I'd do and what convention is

Comment: You're at liberty to do that, I'm just saying that you have a join table and that it's best to use the recommendation I have outlined. I even linked to another website which shares a similar strategy. If you want to do it your way, you'll have to fix the flow to accommodate any errors you get

Comment: [Yep](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many) `The simplest rule of thumb is that you should set up a has_many :through relationship if you need to work with the relationship model as an independent entity.` -- if you want to use `id`, just make a model for your join table and use `has_many :through` (I can update if required). HABTM - I believe - doesn't work with `id` in the table though

Comment: `stack level too deep` basically means infinite recursion -- do you have time to jump into chat?

Comment: Richard i found the error and is still  SystemStackError (stack level too deep):

Comment: When are you available to chat again?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code.

params.require(:user).permit(:name, :user_ejecutives => [])

Hey, I think you have "ejecutive_id" column declared as integer but when loop through "user_ejecutives" you are getting each value as string, May be this is causing the issue, Kindly update your create action to below.

```
  def create
    obj_user = User.new(user_params)

    if obj_user.save
      params[:user_ejecutives].each do |ejecutive|
        user_ejecutive = UserEjecutive.create(user_id: obj_user.id, ejecutive_id: ejecutive.to_i)
        user_ejecutive.save
      end
    end
  end
```