# Save array in DB when checked more than one checkbox

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox

I have a problem greatest!! I guess that really want Array, look my console when I checked just one:

```
{"value_solve"=>["", "", "333", ""], "contract_number"=>["33"]}
-----
  SQL (317.5ms)  UPDATE "authorizations" SET "value_solve" = '', "situation" = 2 WHERE "authorizations"."contract_number" = ?  [["contract_number", "33"]]
```

After, when I checked just one, the first:

```
{"value_solve"=>["111", "", "", ""], "contract_number"=>["11"]}
-----
  SQL (317.5ms)  UPDATE "authorizations" SET "value_solve" =  '111 ', "situation" = 2 WHERE "authorizations"."contract_number" = ?  [["contract_number", "11"]]
```

And, for last, when I just more then one:

```
{"contract_number"=>["11", "44"], "value_solve"=>["111", "", "", "444"]}
-----
  SQL (297.7ms)  UPDATE "authorizations" SET "value_solve" = '111', "situation" = 2 WHERE "authorizations"."contract_number" = ?  [["contract_number", "11"]]
  SQL (121.9ms)  UPDATE "authorizations" SET "value_solve" = '', "situation" = 2 WHERE "authorizations"."contract_number" = ?  [["contract_number", "44"]]
```

And this is my controller:

```
@selected_ids = params[:authorization][:contract_number]
  @authorizations = Authorization.where("contract_number in (?)", @selected_ids)
  auth_params = params[:authorization]
  auth_params[:contract_number].zip(auth_params[:value_solve]).each do |contract_number, value_solve|
      Authorization.where(contract_number: contract_number).update_all(value_solve: value_solve, situation: 2)
  end
```

Just save the first value on DB, how I can save more then one value? Thanks!

Comment: you can check sending params as an array in rails here: `http://stackoverflow.com/a/16555975/3425913`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, you want the `contract_number` with id `44` to be “associated” with `value_solve == "444"`. If this is correct, you should remove blanks from your `value_solve` array:

```
auth_params[:contract_number].zip(auth_params[:value_solve].reject(&:blank?))...
```

Now `44` is being updated with the second element of `value_solve`, which is apparently an empty string.

See [`Array#zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) for more details.

Comment: FINALLY!!! I love you man! :D more then 1 week trying solve this!!! Thank you very much man!!!