# Rails has_many through creating record with relationship

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a "posts" model, a "teams" model, and a "post_memberships" model. I want "posts" to be related to many "teams" and "teams" to be related to many "posts". I have everything set up properly (i think), but I am unsure of how to create a "post" record with multiple teams related to it.

```
    class Post < ApplicationRecord

        has_many :post_memberships
        has_many :teams,through: :post_memberships
    end

    class Team < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :post_memberships
    has_many :posts,through: :post_memberships

end

    class PostMembership < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :team
    belongs_to :post

end
```

My "post" form sends a multiple select field of team_id's to the create action in the posts_controller:

```
    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)
        if post_params[:teams]
          post_params[:teams].each do |id|

            @post.teams << Team.find(id)

          end
        end

        respond_to do |format|
          if @post.save
            format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :teams)
    end
```

I cannot seem to create a "Post" with a "PostMembership".

Comment: Hi, could you add the ```post_params``` method and the request (console output), so you can make sure that the teams parameter is sent correctly? Because your models and the controller seems to be right.

Comment: def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :teams)
end

Comment: Does it give you an error, or does it return just fine but no post created?

Comment: It creates the post perfectly, just no "PostMembership"

Comment: Right now I am thinking I can only create a PostMembership after the post has been created, unless I can find a way to create them both simultaneously.

Comment: Ok, I think we need the params here, could you put ```p params``` in ```def create``` and post the console output (or whatever debug method you prefer) :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131549/discussion-between-ninigi-and-athleteinaction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a caveat in [using arrays in strong parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549382/how-to-permit-an-array-with-strong-parameters), so you need to change your post_params method:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, teams: [])
end
```

That's not quite the end of it though, because now your Post.new receives an array of ids for the teams association, which should throw `AssociationTypeMismatch`. So we need to change your create method a tiny little bit:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params.except(:teams))
  # ...
```

everything else looks like it should be working :)

Comment: Yup, came to the exact same solution. Thanks again!