# Strong parameters with json array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I allready read this anwer  [how to permit an array with strong parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549382/how-to-permit-an-array-with-strong-parameters) but I cannot figure this situation using params.permit, from a byebug session using rails 4.2:

how can I extract the comments parameters?

```
(byebug) params
{"comments"=>"[{\"comment\":\"ndjsnjakldnfljkasdbfhjae\",\"date\":\"2017-07-20 17:14:38\"}]", "format"=>:json, "controller"=>"airis/observations", "action"=>"create", "id"=>"13534543543"}
(byebug) params.permit(:id)
[2017-07-20 19:14:43 +0200] [f2b3d7c8-c84a-43a5-b48f-0f634be49dc7] Unpermitted parameters: comments, format
{"id"=>"13534543543"}
(byebug) params.permit(:comments)
[2017-07-20 19:14:43 +0200] [f2b3d7c8-c84a-43a5-b48f-0f634be49dc7] Unpermitted parameters: format, id
{"comments"=>"[{\"comment\":\"ndjsnjakldnfljkasdbfhjae\",\"date\":\"2017-07-20 17:14:38\"}]"}
(byebug) params.permit(comments: [:comment, :date])
[2017-07-20 19:14:43 +0200] [f2b3d7c8-c84a-43a5-b48f-0f634be49dc7] Unpermitted parameters: format, id
{"comments"=>nil}
(byebug) params.permit(:id, comments: [:comment, :date])
[2017-07-20 19:14:43 +0200] [f2b3d7c8-c84a-43a5-b48f-0f634be49dc7] Unpermitted parameter: format
{"id"=>"13534543543", "comments"=>nil}
```

or even with this:

```
(byebug) params.permit( :comments => [:comment, :date])
[2017-07-20 19:14:43 +0200] [f2b3d7c8-c84a-43a5-b48f-0f634be49dc7] Unpermitted parameters: format, id
{"comments"=>nil}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
2.3.1 :034 > JSON.parse(params.permit(:comments)[:comments])
Unpermitted parameters: format, id
 => [{"comment"=>"ndjsnjakldnfljkasdbfhjae", "date"=>"2017-07-20 17:14:38"}]
```

`params.permit(:comments)` returns the params hash with only the "comments" k,v pair (dropping the unpermitted parameters, `format` and `id`):

```
2.3.1 :035 > params.permit(:comments)
Unpermitted parameters: format, id
 => {"comments"=>"[{\"comment\":\"ndjsnjakldnfljkasdbfhjae\",\"date\":\"2017-07-20 17:14:38\"}]"}
```

`params.permit(:comments)[:comments]` selects the value for the `:comments` key from the hash:

```
2.3.1 :036 > params.permit(:comments)[:comments]
Unpermitted parameters: format, id
 => "[{\"comment\":\"ndjsnjakldnfljkasdbfhjae\",\"date\":\"2017-07-20 17:14:38\"}]"
```

`JSON.parse(params.permit(:comments)[:comments])` converts the string to a proper ruby array.

From there, you can do as you like with the ruby `array` object.

If you want both `:comments` and `:id`, then just:

```
params.permit(:comments, :id)
Unpermitted parameter: format
 => {"comments"=>"[{\"comment\":\"ndjsnjakldnfljkasdbfhjae\",\"date\":\"2017-07-20 17:14:38\"}]", "id"=>"13534543543"}
```

To get the individual parts:

```
2.3.1 :038 > params.permit(:comments, :id)[:comments]
Unpermitted parameter: format
 => "[{\"comment\":\"ndjsnjakldnfljkasdbfhjae\",\"date\":\"2017-07-20 17:14:38\"}]"
```

and:

```
2.3.1 :039 > params.permit(:comments, :id)[:id]
Unpermitted parameter: format
 => "13534543543"
```

You probably want to wrap it in something like:

```
def clean_params
  @clean_params ||= params.permit(:comments, :id)
end
```

So you can do `clean_params[:comments]` and `clean_params[:id]`.

Comment: Thanks for t'he answer.  happens, if I want to permit id And comments