# Receiving array in POST in Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating a Rails API, and I'm trying to receive an array through a post request. On POSTMAN, my request is:

```
{
    "user": {
        "email": "testuser2@gmail.com",
        "first_name": "Joao Paulo",
        "last_name": "Furtado Silva",
        "city_id": 384,
        "province_id": 2,
        "cuisines": [17,5,2],
        "password":"123456",
        "password_confirmation":"123456"
    }
}
```

On the user model:

```
validates :first_name, :last_name, :city_id, :province_id, :cuisines, :password, :password_confirmation, :presence => true
```

And on User_controller:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :first_name, :last_name, :city_id, :province_id, :password, :password_confirmation, :cuisines)
end
```

Even if I pass my cuisines array to the backend, Rails doesn't recognize it. It says as API response:

```
{
  "status": "Error",
  "message": [
    "Cuisines can't be blank"
  ]
}
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

If I remove `:cuisines` from validation, it works fine. But I'm not supposed to do this. What's the best way to solve this issue?

**SOLUTION SO FAR:**

I removed `:cuisines`  automatic validation from Rails, and validated it manually in a simple code like:

```
#validate cuisines
@cuisines = params.require(:user)[:cuisines] #it comes in array format

if @cuisines.empty?
  render json: {
    status: 'Error',
    message: 'User cuisines are empty',
  }, status: :precondition_failed

  return false
end
```

If someone has a better solution, please post.

Comment: What is data type of column `cuisines` ?

Comment: Its an array, but rails seems to be not recognizing it

Comment: try to send it with `"cuisines[]": [17,5,2],` . let me know if it is working or not

Comment: Still the same error: {
    "status": "Error",
    "message": [
        "Cuisines can't be blank"
    ]
}

Comment: I added my answer , please check it and let me know if it working or not

Answer (score 2):

To declare that the value in params must be an array of permitted scalar values map the key to an empty array:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :first_name, :last_name, 
  :city_id, :province_id, :password, :password_confirmation, :cuisines => [])
end
```

You can see the answer with more details here [how to permit an array with strong parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549382/how-to-permit-an-array-with-strong-parameters?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Ok, this works fine IF I remove the :cuisines from my validates part on User model

Comment: validates :first_name, :last_name,:city_id, :province_id,  :password,:password_confirmation,
            :presence => true

Answer (score 1):

If you are using POSTMAN then try to send it with form-data
Please check below image

[image]

and in your permit method please add cuisines as array

```
 params.require(:user).permit(:email, :first_name, :last_name, 
  :city_id, :province_id, :password, :password_confirmation, :cuisines => [])
```