# attr_accessor returns nil in model while returns the correct value in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model Assignment with `attr_accessor :members`

When I send my ajax request I can see in the terminal the params that are passed, and the my attr_accessor is well set `"members"=>["", "12", "13"]`

Here is an overview:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
 "authenticity_token"=>"YfDZ8VHrrriXLgf2RRHdZtzE8X0V5NFrEOBKZmoCw5mbvqbNKBsUVdBeJSY6HCj4YqcTQi2iiYZFhXx3SYFngw==", 
"assignment"=>{"members"=>["", "12", "13"], ....}
```

However in my model Assignment the value of members accessor returns always nil :

```
before_validation :check_members

def check_members
    throw self.members # this throws: UncaughtThrowError (uncaught throw nil)
end
```

Why am getting nil for members instead the array of values ?

Comment: Can you show more code of the model? show the controller action too

Comment: @arieljuod I solved it, I needed to specify in my strong parameter that :members is an array, I posted the answer to my question bellow, thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

It seems that I needed to specify an "empty array" for the strong parameters, What I had before is this :

```
params.require(:assignment).permit(:title, :members)
```

I turned it to

```
params.require(:assignment).permit(:title, :members => [])
```

Now it's working :)

A related source : [how to permit an array with strong parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549382/how-to-permit-an-array-with-strong-parameters)