# JSON for passing multiple records to POST request to rails API create action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I have a simple API built using

```
rails new my_api --api
```

Then

```
rails g scaffold Model name age
```

I can make a new record using curl POST request like so

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"name": "Fred", "age": "5"}' "http://localhost:3000/model_name"
```

#### Question

Is it possible to submit multiple new records in the same POST request? And if so, what should the JSON look like?

#### What I've tried so far

I've tried variations of `{"name": "Fred", "age": "5"}`, like `{"name": ["Fred", "Mary"], "age": ["5", "6"]}`

The API doesn't reject this JSON, instead, it creates 1 record (not 2), and the values are `nil` instead of the actual data.

#### Note

The current controller code is

```rb
  def create
    @model = Model.new(model_params)

    if @model.save
      render json: @model, status: :created, location: @model
    else
      render json: @model.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

Comment: Have you tried passing array of hashes (multiple records) in the request?

Comment: @Ni3 no I haven't, I'm very new to curl and the above is as far as I've gotten

Comment: @user5783745 Another hint for you: Try using `POSTMAN` app to make your requests. It is very useful when building API's

Comment: @LucasWieloch I did not know of this gem. Thank you I will try it next time :)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, yes.

You built the API, you define exactly what that `POST` request will receive and how it will handle it. Rails `scaffold` auto generated `create` method will not accept multiple records at once in a `JSON` though. You must open the `controller` file that was generated by `rails scaffold` and change it to accept multiple records.

And a little hint, try this structure for a `JSON` with multiple records:

```
[{"name": "Fred", "age": "5"}, {"name": "Fred", "age": "5"}, {"name": "Fred", "age": "5"}]
```

Comment: I popped the controller code into the question above. Is it possible to show a minimal implementation of what you suggest?

Comment: Just remove the line `@model = Model.new(model_params)` and change the `if @model.save` to `if Model.create(model_params)`. That should do the trick, although I am pretty sure you need to change your `model_params` method to permit the new `JSON` array of params. Check [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) for that, they are very helpful

Comment: I will try now.

Comment: I made the changes to the controller. But I get `Completed 400 Bad Request in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 32.1ms)` Followed by `ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: model`. I cannot see in the docs how to modify `model_params` to accept a JSON array? The current method is `params.require(:model).permit(:name, :age)`

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56967541/how-to-alter-params-method-to-accept-a-json-array-in-rails-controller)

Comment: `params.permit([:name, :age])`. See [this](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require) to understand what `require` method does. In that topic you have linked it is mentioned why you got that error. Basically, `require` would ask for a different `JSON` structure such as `{ "model" : [{"name": "Fred", "age": "5"}, {"name": "Fred", "age": "5"}, {"name": "Fred", "age": "5"}]}`

Comment: I now see `(undefined method permit?' for #<Array:0x00007ff2bbb46418>
Did you mean?  permutation):`

Comment: I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549382/how-to-permit-an-array-with-strong-parameters) and indeed it is wrong. If you want to call permit for each element in the array of params, you should loop in that array, instance a new `ActionController::Parameters` and call `permit(:name, :age)` in each one. If you don't want to sanitise params (highly unsafe) you can just change the line `Model.create(model_params)` to `Model.create(params)`