# Rails not updating record when passed an array of association ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

Am I correct in saying that Rails will handle adding associated has_many items to an object if you pass the params in with a definition like tag_ids as an array of ids?

If so, I'm posting the following to my Item controller:-

```
{
    "title": "Bottle",
    "tag_ids": [25, 26]
}
```

What's happening is that the tag_ids are being ignored.  I already added tag with id 25, but 26 isn't being included.

My controller:-

```
# PATCH/PUT /api/items/1
  def update
    if @item.update(item_params)
      render json: @item, include: ['tags']
    else
       render json: @item.errors
    end
  end 

  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:name, :tag_ids)
  end
```

Item `has_and_belongs_to_many` Tags, and they have a join table of `jobs_tags`.  The association works because I get Tags returned in my response above.  I can't seem to add them however.  Any idea where I may be going wrong?

Do I need to explicitly add a `tag_ids` field to the Item model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tag_ids` parameter is an array. But `permit(:name, :tag_ids)` only permits a single `tag_ids` attribute.

Change the permission to:

def item_params
params.require(:item).permit(:name, tag_ids: [])
end

See [how to permit an array with strong parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549382/how-to-permit-an-array-with-strong-parameters) for more details.

Comment: Thanks @spickermann - that didn't work for me though, for some reason.  When I make the POST - my logs show `Parameters: {"title"=>"Bottle 2", "tag_ids"=>[24, 25], "id"=>"5", "item"=>{"title"=>"Bottle 2"}}` - if that helps?  

What's the reason for tags not showing in the second part of this?

Comment: I no longer get `Unpermitted parameter: :tag_ids`, so that's a step forward - however, the record isn't being updated with the ids.  It's still ignoring them.

Comment: OK - found the solution.  I needed to implement your solution above, AND add `item` as a top level object in my JSON.  Not sure why this is required since the other fields update fine without me declaring `item`, but oh well.